# Can I generate the GPG key inside R2Mail2?

Tags: applications, encryption

I just installed [R2Mail2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.rundquadrat.android.r2mail2) and it seems to work fine so far, but I didn't understand the key generation procedure at the beginning.

What is this key for? Is this already a new GPG key-pair I can use? or is it just some internal stuff I don't have to care about?

How can I generate a GPG keypair inside R2Mail2? Or do I need [APG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thialfihar.android.apg) to create my keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation R2Mail2 generates a 2048bit RSA keypair which is used to internally encrypt data like stored key passwords or message content.

You cannot access or backup this keypair since it is generated during the installation.

R2Mail2 has no option to create a keypair for good reasons. For more information see my post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r2mail2-beta-test/RYYaj4tOrwc

regards
stefan

Comment: So the R2Mail2 developer doensn't want to implement a GPG key-generation in an unsecure device like Android for good reasons. Well then: if security isn't that important for you, you can use Openkeychain or APG still.